# How to delete anonymous objects and check if they still exist in c#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Say I have a for loop that creates anonymous objects like so:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace gctest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                myObject newobject = new myObject(i);
            }
        }
    }
    class myObject{
        int i;
        public myObject(int i){
            this.i = i;
            Announcer newannouncer = new Announcer (i); 
            Thread newthread = new Thread (newannouncer.Start);
            newthread.Start ();
        }
        ~myObject()  // destructor
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("=============================Object " + i + " HAS BEEN DESTROYED!=========================");
        }
    }
    class Announcer{
        int i;
        public Announcer(int i){
            this.i = i;
        }
        public void Start ()
        {
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine ("OBJECT" + i + " STILL EXISTS!");
                Thread.Sleep (500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the for loop is run, there aren't any names I can use to reference the myObject instances, which means they are unreferenced and therefore should be garbage collected, right? But that's not what happens. They keep printing the messages which means they still exist, but I have no means to access them or delete them. I also don't see the message printed from the destructor method which means they are not being garbage collected.

How can I delete these anonymous objects that I have created and check that they no longer exist? I don't only want the threads to stop, because I could add another method in the myObjects that restarts the thread. I want the myObject instances to be deleted completely.

EDIT: After 12 minutes of running the objects have finally been garbage collected. Mike was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anonymous objects do in fact get garbage collected. You have no way of knowing that they were not garbage collected; the messages that you see come from the threads that you start, not from your anonymous objects.

If you want to see whether something gets garbage collected, you can do one of two things:

1. The easy thing to do is add a destructor (`~myObject()`) and print "I am being garbage-collected!" from it.
2. The best thing to do (which, though, is a lot more work) is keep a `List` of `WeakReference`s to your objects, and periodically go through the list and see if any of the target references have become null.

Comment: I added a destructor method to myObject and the message in the destructor was never printed (I ran the program for over 10 minutes).

Comment: They have been garbage collected now after 12 minutes.

Comment: That's weird.  They should have been garbage collected almost immediately.  I am not sure why it took so long.

Answer (score 1):

The Common Language Runtime ([CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) keeps track of the threads and the Garbage Collector will not get rid of them. You need to stop your threads and nullify any reference to your thread objects and wait for the Garbage Collector to do the dirty work for you.

Comment: You are absolutely right in what you say, but I am afraid that his problem is not exactly this; I think that first and foremost the problem is the situation that I am describing in my answer.